# How to capture Enter key on date input on Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.61

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using this function to capture Enter/Return key with `onkeypress`, in data entry forms to set focus on next field.

```
   function setFocus(evx, idx)
  {
     var charCode = (evx.which) ? evx.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode == 13) {
        evx.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(idx).focus();
        document.getElementById(idx).select();
        }
  }
```

It was working fine till update of Google Chrome to version 83.0.4103.61. Now pressing Enter on a date field, it opens the date picker calendar instead of calling this function and setting focus on the desired field. Do anyone have some solution to overcome it. My whole application is suffering due to this update.

```html
<html>

<HEAD>
  <script>
    function setFocus(evx, idx) {
      var charCode = (evx.which) ? evx.which : event.keyCode
      if (charCode == 13) {
        evx.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(idx).focus();
        document.getElementById(idx).select();
      }
    }
  </script>
</HEAD>

<body style="width: 1430px">
  <form id="myForm">
    Booking Date: <input id='dt' type="date" onkeypress="return setFocus(event, 'sbt')" name="dob" autofocus="true">
    <br>
    <input id="sbt" type="button" accesskey="s" name="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Run this example on Opera and Chrome, pressing Enter on date field in Opera will set focus to SAVE button, but in Chrome, it will expand date picker.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: Don’t use the date input?

Comment: `event.which` and `event.keyCode` have been deprecated for a while. Use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Comment: My last comment won't solve the issue; it is just a warning. There is also `event.code`. You're better off using a third-party date picker component for now, until the standards for how the native controls should behave are worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported this issue, and they have admitted removing it in the coming release.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1096948